# Как мне защитить ответ от капчи php

Tags: php

В интернете смотрел как создать свою капчу. И я создал капчу.
Вы наверное знаете как это сделать.

Генерируем капчу (код), записываем в куки и хешируем, потом генерируем картинку и передаем на сайт. Я просто сгенерировал её с помощи `ImagePNG` - передал на сайт с помощи url страницы где и происходит генерация.

Форма обработки капчи берет ответ пользователя, и берет из куки хеш капчи. Ответ пользователя хешируется, потом проверяет идентичный ли он с хешом в куки.

И все это работает.
Но я не понимаю как прятать ответ от капчи. Потому что если взять хеш, и ответ капчи, сохранить, и каждый раз менять в куки хеш на тот что я сохранил, и передавать один и тот-же ответ, то форма срабатывает.
Что делать? Как прятать? Или есть другие способы? В интернете только такие и нашел.

Comment: хранить хэш в сессии и никогда не передавать на клиент